# Integer division by negative number

Tags: python, ruby, math

What should integer division -1 / 5 return? I am totally confused by this behaviour. I think mathematically it should be 0, but python and ruby are returning -1.

Why are different languages behaving differently here? Please someone explain. Thanks.

```
| Language  | Code           | Result |
|-----------+----------------+--------|
| ruby      | -1 / 5         |     -1 |
| python    | -1 / 5         |     -1 |
| c         | -1 / 5         |      0 |
| clojure   | (int (/ -1 5)) |      0 |
| emacslisp | (/ -1 5)       |      0 |
| bash      | expr -1 / 5    |      0 |
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant -1 not 1. I don't know the answer and I feel totally confused.

Comment: There is no answer. "Integer division" is not a well-defined concept and each language's specification can choose flooring or truncation towards 0 as its defined result for the operation.

Comment: In Ruby the quotient is rounded toward -infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really tried searching explanation for it, but couldn't find. Probably there is good arguments behind this behaviour?

Comment: Come on, the question is clear: "What should integer division -1 / 5 return?"  The rest of the post is just justification or incentive for this question.  With just a little interpretation I can understand the question as "Why are different languages behaving differently here?" and this is a good question.

No need to close down this post.

Comment: @Wooble that's actually a good answer.

Comment: There have been [many Questions about rounding and integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=integer+division+rounding) for various languages, often with an eye toward overcoming a "rounding down" behavior with "rounding up".  Many of these approaches will help in understanding how rounding works for negatives.

Comment: A nice paper with some C implementations of division and remainder that round different ways: [Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/division-and-modulus-for-computer-scientists/)

Comment: This is not division by negative number. This is negative divided by positive.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Short answer:** Language designers get to choose if their language will round towards zero, negative infinity, or positive infinity when doing integer division. Different languages have made different choices.

**Long answer:** The language authors of Python and Ruby both decided that rounding towards negative infinity makes more sense than rounding towards zero (like C does). The creator of python wrote a blog post about his reasoning [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html). I've excerpted much of it below.

> I was asked (again) today to explain why integer division in Python returns the floor of the result instead of truncating towards zero like C.
>
> For positive numbers, there's no surprise:
>
> ```
> >>> 5//2
> 2
> ```
>
> But if one of the operands is negative, the result is floored, i.e., rounded away from zero (towards negative infinity):
>
> ```
> >>> -5//2
> -3
> >>> 5//-2
> -3
> ```
>
> This disturbs some people, but there is a good mathematical reason.
>   The integer division operation (//) and its sibling, the modulo
>   operation (%), go together and satisfy a nice mathematical
>   relationship (all variables are integers):
>
> ```
> a/b = q with remainder r
> ```
>
> such that
>
> ```
> b*q + r = a and 0 <= r < b
> (assuming a and b are >= 0).
> ```
>
> If you want the relationship to extend for negative a (keeping b
>   positive), you have two choices: if you truncate q towards zero, r
>   will become negative, so that the invariant changes to 0 <= abs(r) <
>   otherwise, you can floor q towards negative infinity, and the
>   invariant remains 0 <= r < b. [update: fixed this para]
>
> In mathematical number theory, mathematicians always prefer the latter
>   choice (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)). For Python, I made the same choice
>   because there are some interesting applications of the modulo
>   operation where the sign of a is uninteresting. Consider taking a
>   POSIX timestamp (seconds since the start of 1970) and turning it into
>   the time of day. Since there are 24*3600 = 86400 seconds in a day,
>   this calculation is simply t % 86400. But if we were to express times
>   before 1970 using negative numbers, the "truncate towards zero" rule
>   would give a meaningless result! Using the floor rule it all works out
>   fine.

Comment: However, when the divisor is negative the results are not what I would have expected. E.g. `5 // -2` gives quotient `-3` and remainder `-1`. I think quotient `-2` and remainder `1` would have made more sense (so that we always have `0 <= r < abs(b)` and, of course, `a = b*q+r`.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Then you prefer Euclidean division.

Answer (score 7):

Integer division is implementation specific. From Wikipedia's [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> Many implementations use **truncated division** where the quotient is defined by [truncation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) *q* = trunc(*a*/*n*), in other words it is the first integer in the direction of 0 from the exact rational quotient, and the remainder by *r*=*a* − *n* *q*. Informally speaking the quotient is "rounded towards zero", and the remainder therefore has the same sign as the dividend.
>
> [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) described **floored division** where the quotient is defined by the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function) *q*=floor(*a*/*n*) and the remainder *r* is
>
> [image: r = a - nq = a - n \left\lfloor {a \over n} \right\rfloor.]
>
> Here the quotient is always rounded downwards (even if it is already negative) and the remainder has the same sign as the divisor.