# What is the difference between 3/2 and -3/2?

Tags: python, division

I am beginner in programming and Python.  I am doing some simple maths operations. So `3/2` in Python interpreter gives `1` as we know. But `-3/2` gives `-2`. Can you point out the difference here?

Comment: `3/2` -> 1.5, rounded DOWN to 1. `-3/2` -> -1.5, rounded DOWN to -2.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19518866/190597 for an explanation of why Python rounds towards negative infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, `/` performs integer division. What this means is that the result, if it is not an integer, is **rounded down** to the next integer value. When the value is negative, this naturally rounds to a greater-magnitude negative number.

Intuitively, the result of integer division is simply the [mathematical floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the result of float division. For this reason, integer division is also commonly referred to as [*floor division*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-floor-division).

```
floor(1.5)  # Returns 1.0
floor(-1.5)  # Returns -2.0
```

---

It's possible to alter this behavior in Python 2 by putting `from __future__ import division` at the top of your module. This import will make the `/` operator indicate only true division (float division), and enable explicit floor division (integer division) with the `//` operator. These conventions are the standard in Python 3.

```
from __future__ import division

print(3/2)  # 1.5
print(3//2)  # 1
```

---

As @Dunes notes in the comments, it's worth noting that `-` has a higher precedence than `/`, and therefore `-3/2` is equivalent to `(-3)/2` rather than `-(3/2)`. If the division were applied first, the result would indeed be `-1`.

Comment: i think rounding down is typically called `floor` +1 for explaining it better than me

Comment: Worth noting that `-` is unary operator here and binds more tightly than the division operator. If it were the other way around then the results would be the same.

Comment: In Python 3.4.2, `int(-1.5)` returns `-1`.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Well I'll be! I've removed the offending lies from the answer!

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: Same result in Python 2 since forever. The `int()` function truncates (i.e. same as rounding toward zero), and it says so right in the docs. It's not related to division at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
-3/2 == -1.5 , floor(-1.5)  = -2
```

likewise

```
 3/2 == 1.5 , floor(1.5)  = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has two division operators.

1. `/`
2. `//`

Here, `//` will always round the result to the nearest integer (irrespective of the type of operands). This is called **floor division**. But `/` will round to the nearest integer, if both the operands are integers wheres it does the actual division if either of the operands is a float.

The difference can be clearly understood with this example,

```
>>> 11/4
2
>>> 11.0/4
2.75
>>> 11//4
2
>>> 11.0//4.0
2.0
```

Quoting from [Python Documentation on **floor division**](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-floor-division),

> Mathematical division that **rounds down to nearest integer**. The floor division operator is `//`. For example, the expression `11 // 4` evaluates to `2` in contrast to the `2.7`5 returned by float true division. **Note that `(-11) // 4` is `-3` because that is `-2.75` rounded downward**. See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238).

The last line in the quoted text would be the answer to your actual question.

Comment: Floor division and rounding to the nearest integer are two non-equivalent concepts. In Python 3.4.2, `5 // 3` will yield 1, and `round(5 / 3)` will yield 2. The `//` operator will always round towards negative infinity.