# Why python round mechanism in division different from c and java?

Tags: python, integer-division

When solving a problem in leetcode, I found:

```
>>> -6/132
-1
```

in python, which seems a bit weird, as it behaves different from c++ and java.

It seems that c++ and java is using **round to zero** mechanism and python is using **round to -∞** mechanism.

Did python do this for any special purposes?

Comment: try -6//132 in Python2 or -6/132 in Python3

Comment: Actually, I want to ask why python do **round to -∞** instead of **round to zero** as c++ and java, but no such answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/python-negative-integer-division-surprising-result).

Comment: What do you mean *"why"*? It's just a choice. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19517868/3001761

Comment: "Integer division" is not a well-defined concept and each language's specification can choose flooring or truncation towards 0 as its defined result for the operation. --- This comment is clear enough.

Comment: Have to disagree.  It is a well-defined concept, and it's not just a choice.  The correct thing to do is heavily context-dependent.  For example, if you are doing signal processing (which is often done with fixed point, aka integers), rounding towards zero may add unacceptable distortion to a signal, as the "bucket" at zero is now wider than all the other buckets.