# Difference in divison of -a//b and a//b in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am currently working on python 2.7.
I observed that if we have : -10//6 the answer is -2 while 10//6 yields 1
Can i know why is there the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19518866/4954037

Answer (score 0):

`//` performs the floor operation.

- 10/6 is 1.666, the floor of which is 1
- -10/6 is -1.666, the floor of which is -2