# BMI app print result is 0 even with variable being hard coded

Tags: ios, swift

Firstly Thanks to all upcoming answers .

I am new to `swift` programming . I am testing out many things lol . I am trying to do a `bmi` app. I am using  `print()` in order to check all values of my variables. 
I am not able to understand why `imc` value is `0` . Did I miss something ? What's the logic? I tried to hard code it with quotien `90/32400` or `x/ySquare` same result. I am still getting `quotien = 0`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        imcCalculator()
    }


    func imcCalculator () {
        let myHeight = Int(heightTextfield.text!)
        let myWeight = Int(weightTextField.text!)
        let x = myWeight!
        let y = myHeight!

        //let imc =  Int(Int(x / pow(y, 2)) * 10000)
        let ySquare = y * y
        let quotien = 90 / 32400
        let imc = (x/ySquare)*10000
        if imc > 25 {
            resultLabel.text = " Your BMI is \(imc) . You are overweight"
        }    
        else if imc  18 {
            resultLabel.text = " Your BMI is \(imc) . You have a normal weight"
        }
        else {
            resultLabel.text = "Your BMI is \(imc) . You are underweight"
        }
        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(ySquare)
        print(quotien)
        print(imc)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing math with integers.  In integer math, a result like 6/7 is 0 because the remainder is dropped.  Use `Double` for your calculations.

Comment: 90 / 32400 is zero, it's integer division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is called [*Truncation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation), or *Integer division*. The result of integer division [differs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19517868/2907715) from language to language. And as stated by the Swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2884531):

> For integer types, any remainder of the division is discarded

That's why `let quotien = 90 / 32400` will give `0` as a result.

I would suggest you use Doubles instead, and your code might look like this:

```
func imcCalculator () {

    guard let myHeight = Double("6"), let myWeight = Double("70") else {
        fatalError("Error in the text fields")
    }

    let x = myWeight
    let y = myHeight

    //let imc =  Int(Int(x / pow(y, 2)) * 10000)
    let ySquare: Double = y * y
    let quotien: Double = 90.0 / 32400.0
    let imc: Double = (myHeight / ySquare) * 10000

    let imcString: String = String(format: "Your BMI is %.2d", imc)

    if imc > 25 {
        resultLabel.text = imcString + " . You are overweight"
    }
    else if imc < 25 && imc > 18 {
        resultLabel.text = imcString + " . You have a normal weight"
    }
    else {
        resultLabel.text = imcString + " . You are underweight"
    }

    print("x =", x)
    print("y =", y)
    print("ySquare =", ySquare)
    print("quotien =", quotien)
    print("imc =", imc)
}
```

The point is: ***Arithmetic operations between elements of a certain type, give results of the same type***.

Thus, when dividing for example `1` by `2`, you should expect the result to be an integer too. And it's a convention to define the integer part of the quotient as the result of the division of the two numbers. 1 divided by 2 (in real number division) gives 0.5, the integer part of that is 0.

On the other hand, `1.0/2.0` is `0.5` since both the Dividend and Divisor are infered to be Doubles. If you don't add the `.0` after at least one them, thene fractional part is discarded.

You can try this in a playground:

```
3/10          //0
3.0/10.0      //0.3
3.0/10        //0.3
3/10.0        //0.3
```

---

As noted by **@Martin R**, the result of integer division differs from the quotient of [*Euclidean division*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Examples) when the Dividend (numerator) is negative, since *truncation always rounds toward zero*. Here is what is meant by that:

- In integer division: `(-3)/10 equals 0`
- In Euclidean division: `The quotient of (-3)/10 is -1`

Comment: oh thank you for your answer did not know that . Thanks again .

Comment: It is *truncating* division, not euclidean. (They differ if the numerator is negative.)

Comment: @MartinR your comments make my day, everytime! I've updated the answer.