# Negative number division in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can anybody explain the below result of the division of a negative number:

```
2.6.1 :001 > -25/24
 => -2 
2.6.1 :002 > 25/24
 => 1
```

Why is it `-2` instead of `-1`?

More examples on *weird* behaviour:

```
2.6.1 :003 > 24/25
 => 0 
2.6.1 :004 > -24/25
 => -1
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: It's because the floor of `(-1 - 1/24)` equals `-2`.

Comment: Does it mean that Ruby always calls `#floor` under the hood in case of Integer division? And where does `(-1 - 1/24)` come from?

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation behind the behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19518866/1954610

Comment: @TomLord Wow, so there were some historical discussions like that, thanks a lot! After  10 years of Ruby, I've never asked myself about it until today :).

Answer (score 5):

Different programming languages use different definitions for (negative) integer division. Ruby uses the one described by [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) in [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics), p. 82.<sup>†</sup>

It can be illustrated by an example: let's say we are working with weeks. Our weeks start on Sunday. Numbers are zero-based, so we begin at week `0`, day `0`:

```
----- 0 -----
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
S M T W T F S
^
```

If we move *forward* by 9 days, we are at week `1`, day `2`:

```
----- 0 -----   ----- 1 -----
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
S M T W T F S   S M T W T F S
                    ^
```

These values are returned by `/` and `%`:

```
9 / 7 #=> 1
9 % 7 #=> 2
```

If we move *backward* by 9 days (from 0), we are at week `-2`, day `5`:

```
---- -2 -----   ---- -1 -----   ----- 0 -----
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   0 1 2 3 4 5 6   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
S M T W T F S   S M T W T F S   S M T W T F S
          ^
```

Using `/` and `%`:

```
-9 / 7 #=> -2
-9 % 7 #=> 5
```

---

<sup>†</sup> There's a funny note on the margin of that page:

> *Beware of computer languages that use another definition.*

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. By the way, the link to [SO Knuth](https://stackoverflow.com/wiki/Donald_Knuth) resource is broken.

Comment: @belgoros it was meant to point to Wikipedia, fixed it :-)

Comment: This is concrete explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A way you can think about integer division is:

1. You do the floating point division.
2. You round the result down.

Hence:

```
(25.0 / 24.0).floor  # => 1
(-25.0 / 24.0).floor # => -2
```

Answer (score 3):

I could simply find desired functionality by using parenthesis,

```
-(25/24)
# => -1
```

Perhaps, **why -25/24 surprised you:**

For the actual values in float division provide you `-1.041`

Your result using integer division is being rounded down toward the more negative value of -2. This is also known as **Floor division**

Comment: Pheu, this one just adds another one question: `-25/24 => -2`, but  `(-25/24) => -1`

Comment: @belgoros, nice question, I found answer in python doc. Please check edited answer.

Comment: thank you. So my suggestion was correct about calling `#floor` at the end of every division under the hood? I didn't find any answer in Ruby docs.

Comment: @belgoros, Yes it was all about floor to negative side :)

Comment: @belgoros, it's all about precedence, so `-(25.0/24.0).floor` it's like `-((25.0/24.0).floor) #--> -(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Interger division in Ruby returns floor or the floating point result of the division:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Numeric.html#method-i-div

> Uses `/` to perform division, then converts the result to an integer. Numeric does not define the `/` operator; this is left to subclasses.
>
> Equivalent to `num.divmod(numeric)[0]`.

And [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) uses `floor`:
:

```
q = floor(x/y)
x = q*y + r
```

Comment: I have not asked about `#divmod` method but `#/`.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: it is really unclear (IMHO) that all the call to `#/` method will use `#floor`.